# Is ice considered food or drink in Halacha?

Tags: halacha, food, shiurim-measurements, water

Is ice considered food or drink in Halacha? So for example, if one would eat an kezais of ice on yom Kippur, but it would not be equal to a reviyis, would he be liable for a chatas?

Comment: Audrey II, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your interesting question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: Well, there is a concern of nolad when ice melts into water on shabbos... That would imply that ice is considered distinct from water, and the only functional difference between cold water and ice is the crystalline state...

Answer (score 5):

From [Din Online](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/07/19/hagafen-blessing-for-ices/):

> Poskim discuss the status of ice cream or ices–are they considered as
>   liquids or solids? According to some poskim they are considered
>   liquids, and would therefore be covered by the hagafen blessing (see
>   especially Sephardi poskim: Or Le-Zion14:18; Yakut Yosef 3:177, 10;
>   see also Ben Ish Chai, Masei 8; see also Be’er Moshe 1:11, and Vezos
>   Ha-Berachah p.44, inthe name of Rav Elyashiv).
>
> However, others write that they have the halachah of solids (see Shaar
>   Ha-Zion 158:1; Mekor Ha-Berachah p.110, inthe name of the Steipler;
>   Betzeil Ha-Chochmah 3:114, 4 distinguishes between ice creams that are
>   made with many different ingredients, and ices that are predominantly
>   frozen water).
>
> Therefore, some recite a blessing over the ice cream even in a meal,
>   and even after reciting hagafen at the beginning. This is probably the
>   common custom among Ashkenazim. Most Sephardim do not recite a
>   blessing on the ice cream, and leave eating the ice cream until after
>   benching, following the ruling of Rav Ovadyah Yosef and other Sephardi
>   poskim.
>
> ***For ices that are licked and not chewed, it appears that this is
>   certainly considered drinking and not eating, and the hagafen blessing
>   will suffice.***
>   (My Emphasis)

From [Daily Halacha](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1563):

> Rabbi Moshe Stern of Debereczyn, in his work Be'er Moshe (vol. 1,
>   11:2), rules that Halacha indeed treats ice cream as a liquid, and not
>   as a solid, and thus it is covered by the Beracha recited over bread
>   or the Beracha recited over wine. This view is codified as well by
>   Hacham Yishak Yosef in his work Kol Torah, in the name of his father,
>   Hacham Ovadia Yosef. The work "Ve'zot Ha'beracha" (p. 100) likewise
>   cites this ruling in the name of several leading Halachic authorities.

From [Eretz Hemdah](http://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=99&article=313):

> a few poskim make the following claim. Ice cream is a liquid that is
>   served as a solid because people enjoy it at an artificially cold
>   temperature. Since accepted practice is not to make a beracha on
>   liquids during a meal, including during dessert, one should not make a
>   beracha on ice cream. Yalkut Yosef (on OC167, 10) rules this way in
>   the name of his father (Rav Ovadya). There are reports that Rav Moshe
>   Feinstein ruled this way as well (see Vezot Haberacha, pg. 74). One
>   could say that it is logical to call ice cream a liquid only when it
>   is based heavily on milk and/or water, not when it is a mixture of
>   eggs, soy products, and sugar (i.e., pareve ice cream) (see opinions
>   in Piskei Teshuvot 177:(24)). Perhaps Rav Moshe was speaking about
>   classic ice cream; however, Rav Ovadya does not accept this
>   distinction.

It appears that many poskim treat ice-cream and frozen fruit juices (ices) as liquids for the purposes of determining whether they are exempt from brachos during a meal. This means that we would use the shiur of a revi'is when determining shiur requirements for the bracha achrona, therefore the consumption of ice on Yom Kippur would only be a violation of inuy if one consumed the equivalent of a revi'is of water once it is melted rather than the smaller kezayis shiur.

Comment: Interesting answer, but the question was asking about ice specifically, not frozen liquid treats. See my comment on the OP - the concern of nolad vis a vis ice on shabbos implies that we treat it as a solid and therefore distinct from water. I can't definitively point to a rav that says that, however...

Comment: There is no difference. What brocha and which shiur indicates how we look at it. See my emphasis added in first reference. Further nolad of ice into water (when in the water is NOT nolad) as its not nikkar. They may be different states but not different entities (if that makes sense)

Comment: Yes, but for water/ice you would be making the same bracha regardless, and water is weird when it comes to brachos (it's the only consumable that can't be yotzei with an accidental mezonos) so it might be incomparable to other frozen goods. Ice in water is not nolad because the melt is batel to the existing standing water. We have a similar situation by demai and by urinating into a pool - it is batel tipa tipa.

Comment: Why do you assume that ice is only water? Why cant the OP be using ice to refer to anything that has reached a state of solidified liquid?

Comment: "and thus it is covered by the beracha recited ***over bread OR*** the beracha recited over wine." This implies it's in an indefinite state (that it received coverage, but it's unclear WHICH bracha gave it coverage). That's not material to answering the question at hand. You can have coagulated milk (cheese) and even coagulated juices/wines (jelly). You can't coagulate plain water into a solid.

Comment: Because the OP would have said "a frozen liquid." No one refers to ice-cream or ice pops as straight "ice." At the very least they use the lashon "ices." Stam ice is colloquially understood to be water.

Comment: Understood. But the references cited above all address  that issue. If ice is considered a liquid or a solid and would they be covered in the respective brachos.

Comment: ***He's not asking about whether there is a bracha!*** "So for example, if one would eat an kezais of ice on yom Kippur, but it would not be equal to a reviyis, would he be liable for a chatas?" Your answer in no way addresses the question as to whether pure ice is a liquid or a solid FOR DETERMINING SHIUR ACHILAH VESHTIYA. I like your sources, but they don't help here. Please expand your answser to address the actual question.

Comment: Of course it answers that directly. These are all nafkaminas from the yesod of whether it is a solid or liquid ie. Reviis or kzyais. If its covered by a hagafen or not. I don't understand your issue

Comment: Please see my edits to your answer. I've attempted to trace your reasoning based upon your sources - your conclusion is implicit, but requires some steps to get there that needed explication.

Comment: NP. I knew YOU understood what you meant and how it was an answer, but it took me a bit of pulling to figure out your meaning... :)