# Are there any limitations for an inclusion blessing?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

There is a rule that if you are eating multiple items that are in the same blessing category (e.g. shehakol) then you only say one blessing and have in mind the other items.

Does this inclusion have an expiration?

For example you are having ice cream and have in mind to have tea right after when you recite the shehakol blessing how much time after the ice cream can you have the tea without an additional blessing?

On a relates note, does the tea need to be already prepared (i.e. not in front of you) at the time of the blessing or can you make it after finishing the ice cream?

Comment: I think you want to add that all these foods are with you when you make the Bracha. Bringing food from another location would change the Din.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, in the second question I am asking if the tea is not yet prepared (i.e. not in front of you).

Comment: One thing to note about intention that tends to get lost on these kinds of qestions: we assume a "default level" of intent, such as by korbanos where "no explicit intention" is sufficient for "proper intent" to avoid pigul, etc. Generally, it's assumed that anything physically present before you is covered by the appropriate bracha without needing to single it out (similar to being someich on the Ba'al haBayis for hamotzi on a meal).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no time limit for one bracha covering another food. [According to Halachipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bracha_Rishona) as long as you don't have an interruption of thought (such as changing locations or making a bracha achrona), no new bracha is required. Of course, you should eat some of the first food immediately after making the bracha, but after that, the bracha rishona could last all day if you never get up and move.

Comment: This seems to contradict with what R' Bodner says in *Halachos of Brachos*. Something along the lines of if you had a solid but didn't have in mind the liquid then the liquid is not covered - implying that in the case where you did have in mind that it would be covered.

Comment: Yet the Kitzur says וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם טוֹב לְבָרֵךְ עַל מְעַט סֻכָּר בִּרְכַּת שֶׁהַכֹּל לִפְטוֹר אֶת הַקָּפֶה in סימן מג. I want to check that MB you are quoting.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I have added the text of the MB to the answer. He says explicitly that food cannot exempt a drink even if he had intention for it to do so, and even if they were on the table together.

Comment: @Daniel - incorrect! He says explicitly that if they were on the table together - or you had explicit intention to eat them too - then one Bracha exempts both types. אא"כ means UNLESS.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Oh I have no idea why I read that as אפילו אם כן

Comment: "bracha rishona could last all day if you never get up and move" - really? See Kitzur 51:14 that you'd have to make another bracha if you are hungry again - http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0050_L2 - אָכַל וְשָׁתָה וְלֹא בֵּרַךְ מִיָּד בְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה, יָכוֹל לְבָרֵךְ עַד שְׁעַת עִכּוּל, ..... וּלְאַחַר זְמַּנִּים אֵלּוּ, אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְבָרֵךְ עוֹד. וּמִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָּקִי לְשַׁעֵר, רָאוּי לוֹ כְּשֶׁנִּזְכַּר שֶׁלֹּא בֵּרַךְ בְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה, לְבָרֵךְ עַל מִין מִמִּין שֶׁאָכַל וְיֹאכַל וִיבָרֵךְ בְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה, לִפְטוֹר גַּם אֶת הָרִאשׁוֹן

Comment: @DannySchoemann But maybe you won't get hungry again...

Comment: @Daniel See also the first paragraph in [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23556). Additionally, there is a dispute over whether ice cream is considered a food or a drink (see [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56812) and [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7962)).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem from the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן נא - כללים בברכה אחרונה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0050_L2)  that the Bracha is valid only as long as you're not hungry (or thirsty) again.

He states that if one is not sure if one is hungry/thirsty again - and significant time has passed and one has not made the after-Bracha - then one should make another Bracha, eat again, and then make the after-Bracha:

> **סעיף יד':** 
>   אָכַל וְשָׁתָה וְלֹא בֵּרַךְ מִיָּד בְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה, יָכוֹל לְבָרֵךְ עַד שְׁעַת עִכּוּל, דְּהַיְנוּ כָּל זְמַן שֶׁאֵינוֹ תָּאֵב לֶאֱכוֹל פֵּרוֹת. וּלְאַחַר שְׁתִיָּה, כָּל זְמַן שֶׁאֵינוֹ צָמֵא. וּלְאַחַר זְמַּנִּים אֵלּוּ, אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְבָרֵךְ עוֹד. וּמִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָּקִי לְשַׁעֵר, רָאוּי לוֹ כְּשֶׁנִּזְכַּר שֶׁלֹּא בֵּרַךְ בְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה, לְבָרֵךְ עַל מִין מִמִּין שֶׁאָכַל וְיֹאכַל וִיבָרֵךְ בְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה, לִפְטוֹר גַּם אֶת הָרִאשׁוֹן (קפ"ד). ‏

Regarding your second question `does the tea need to be already prepared (i.e. not in front of you) at the time of the blessing or can you make it after finishing the ice cream`:

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch states in [סימן נ - כללים בברכה ראשונה מברכת הנהנין](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0049_L2) that any food not in front you while you make the Bracha, is excluded from the Bracha - even if you had explicit intention to consume it when you made the Bracha.

> **סעיף ג':** 
>   הַדָּבָר שֶׁמְבָרְכִין לְאָכְלוֹ או לִשְׁתֹּתוֹ אוֹ לְהָרִיחַ בּוֹ אוֹ לַעֲשׂוֹת בּוֹ מִצְוָה, צָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּקַּח אוֹתוֹ קִדֶם הַבְּרָכָה בְּיַד יְמִינוֹ, וִיכַוֵּן אֵיזֶה בְּרָכָה הוּא צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ עָלָיו, כְּדֵי שֶׁכְּשֶׁיַזְכִּיר אֶת הַשֵּׁם שֶׁהוּא עִקַּר הַבְּרָכָה, יֵדַע מַה שֶּׁיְסַיֵם וִיבָרֵךְ. וְאִם לֹא אֲחָזוֹ כְּלָל, אֶלָּא שֶׁהָיָה לְפָנָיו כְּשֶׁבֵּרֵךְ עָלָיו, יָצָא. אֲבָל **אִם לֹא הָיָה לְפָנָיו כְּלָל כְּשֶׁבֵּרַךְ, אֶלָּא שֶׁהֵבִיאוּ לוֹ אַחַר כָּךְ, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁבִּשְׁעַת הַבְּרָכָה הָיְתָה דַּעְתּוֹ עָלָיו, לֹא יָצָא וְצָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ שֵׁנִית**. 
>   ‏